# Can we have inversion with temporal expressions?

Tags: time, subject-verb-inversion

Is it correct to say:

> "On Friday is a concert at Trafalgar Square."

or do we have to say:

> "On Friday there is a concert at Trafalgar Square."

I know that inversion can occur with locative phrases ("*Outside were five police officers*", "*Into the room rolled a ball*") though I have some doubts when it comes to an example such as "*On the table is a book*".

Comment: I would say no, it is not grammatical. My (speculative) explanation for this is that the location is a complement of _is_, but the time is an adjunct. I have no problem with "On the table is a book".

Comment: _There's a concert, Friday, at Trafalgar Square_ is also acceptable (to me).

Comment: In response to Colin's comment, there's no problem with "The concert is on Friday", where the complement of "be" is a temporal PP.

Comment: We do use at least one type of temporal expression in a fairly similar  way: 'Today is the day of the Royal Wedding' / '2012 was the year of the aardvark', though here 'today' etc are probably best analysed as nouns. // Otherwise, I'd stick with the existential there constructions.

Comment: @ColinFine Yes. One could of course say "Friday is Jane's birthday", where the day is the complement.

Comment: @NigelJ Also "There is a concert in Trafalgar Square on Friday" is perfectly natural. But perhaps that is the base sentence the OP is trying to invert.

Answer (score 1):

(From **[Bright Hub Education](https://www.brighthubeducation.com/english-homework-help/46995-the-nominal-functions-of-prepositions-and-prepositional-phrases/)**)

> The prepositional phrases can  perform six
>   nominal functions. Nominal functions are grammatical functions
>   prototypically performed by nouns, noun phrases, and noun clauses. The
>   six nominal functions prepositional phrases are:
>
> ```
> Subject
> Subject complement
> Direct object
> Object complement
> Indirect object
> Prepositional complement
> ```
>
> **Prepositional phrases of location and time most often perform nominal
>   functions.**
>
> *Behind the shed needs mowing.*
>
> *Before ten is a bad time to call me.*
>
> *Under the refrigerator is disgusting!*

In the light of this explanation, I believe, the OP's following sentences are grammatically acceptable.

*"On Friday is a concert at Trafalgar Square."*

*"On the table is a book".*

The following example sentence (from **[The Internet Grammar of English](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/function/subjpp.htm)**) shows a prepositional phrase of time functioning as the subject of the sentence.

> **Prepositional Phrases functioning as Subject**
>
> Less commonly, the Subject may be realised by a prepositional phrase:
>
> *After nine is a good time to ring*
>
> **Prepositional phrases as Subject typically refer to time or to space.**

Comment: No, these constructions are not relevant. _On the table_ in _On the table would be a good place to look_ is performing a nominal function. In _On the table is a book_ it is not, it is purely locative, and is not the subject. In _On Friday is when you might catch me_ (which I find just barely acceptable, as a native speaker), _On Friday_ is a subject nominal, but in _On Friday is a concert at Trafalgar Square_ it can't be.

Comment: @ColinFine, You said *On the table* of "On the table is a book" is not the subject, it is locative. Is *On the table is a book* a sentence? What is the subject of the sentence? Can't a *locative* phrase be in the nominative case?

Comment: _On the table is a book_ is a perfectly good sentence, and I believe the subject is _a book_. This is different from _Behind the shed needs mowing_, which is saying something about  "(the patch of grass) behind the shed". _Behind the shed_ is grammatically a locative phrase, but semantically it is referring to "the things which are ...", or more specifically "the grass which is ...". In _on the table is a book_ it is not referring to "the things which are on the table", but giving a location for the subject, the book.